# Asian websites don't use HTTPS

Tags: tls

In America and Europe, HTTPS is quite popular, but in most Asian countries it isn't. The majority of China, Japan and Korea's top websites don't use HTTPS.

Are they using another method to protect the privacy and integrity of the exchanged data?   If so, what method?

Comment: Do you have any references to support that claim?

Comment: http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries/CN http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries/KR http://www.alexa.com/topsites/acountries/JP A majority of them don't use HTTPS

Comment: http://www.qq.com/ chinas number one email provider. http://fc2.com/ Japans number one blog site. There are so many more those are just two examples.  For more examples click on the links above

Comment: Korea use to have an atrocious ActiveX based encryption system (not sure if they finally got rid of it).

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't think they did.  I know to use online banking you need to install really horrible slow software on your computer in Korea.  Thats probably what your talking about

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not know Chinese but by looking at [qq.com](http://www.qq.com/) I see that the [login page](https://mail.qq.com/cgi-bin/loginpage) is on HTTPS. This is just an example that the HTTPS pages may not be the front ones. You will find the same case in some "portal type" European sites ([wp.pl](http://www.wp.pl/) being one example): the front page (with information) is on HTTP and any sensitive one (email for instance) is on HTTPS.

To answer you edit: SSL gives you easily two practical mechanisms:

- the ability to check if the server you connect to is actually the one you expect to connect (a mismatched certificate would be an alert)
- the ability to encrypt your traffic to the site

You could roll out your own mechnisms in your application to cover both use cases. It just does not make much sense: you would probably do it wrong and it would cost you a lot of resources to have a reasonable implementation.

In the typical case of the few pages I checked from the list you mention, no other such mechanism is used (i.e. it is either HTTP or HTTPS).

Comment: The second part of your answer doesn't exactly respond to the `Are they using another method...` part of the question. I think you're implying that they don't, but you don't state that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I didnt know that the login page was in HTTPS.  I thought mixing HTTP with HTTPS was dangerous.  You're encrypting traffic, a majority of the users go to front page, the HTTP one.  So it kind of defeats the purpose of HTTPS

Comment: @NeilSmithline: correct, I updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: @Snewman8771: it is dangerous (to some extend only) to mix HTTP and HTTPS **on the same page**. You get a warning from your browser about that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  All of Asia's top websites, with the exception of a few, security is pretty tight.  Thats the reason I was wondering and most arent using a WAF.

Comment: @Snewman8771 "defeats the purpose" - What is, in your opinion, the purpose of encrypting downloading of the front page - where everyone gets same, publicly available data? If you want to protect traffic using HTTPS, you should have something valuable to protect in the first place.

Comment: @Agent_L I would think that protecting the navigation to the login page is pretty important. See Exploiting the HTTP to HTTPS Pattern section here: http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/01/ssl-is-not-about-encryption.html

Comment: @WoJ It's dangerous to use http as an entryway to anything requiring security. The pages that normally link to https pages could be modified to stay http and thus modifiable, and the user might not notice. Whereas if there are no http entry pages then there would be no opportunity to do this.

Comment: @Rick Not to mention that an attacker could easily steal any session tokens created over an HTTPS connection if the user then visits an HTTP page on the same site after logging in.

Comment: @Ajedi32 yes assuming they didn't use an https only cookie, which would only help if all the restricted pages were https.

Comment: @Rick thats what I was getting at.  Thanks for summarizing for me ! :)

Comment: I don't know why they put it my question on hold.  These answers are based on facts.